# Flux with Helm GitOps

Tags: kubernetes, helm

I am running k0s (v1.25.2+k0s.0) on WSL(Ubuntu 22.04).

I am trying to install ElasticSearch's Kibana on my cluster, but:

> ✗ HelmRelease reconciliation failed: install retries exhausted

**flux get all -A:**
[![flux get all -A output][1]][1]

**source.yaml**

```
apiVersion: source.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta2
kind: HelmRepository
metadata:
  name: elastic
  namespace: elastic
spec:
  interval: 1m0s
  url: https://helm.elastic.co
```

**helmrelease.yaml**

```
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: elastic-kibana
  namespace: elastic
spec:
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: kibana
      reconcileStrategy: ChartVersion
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: elastic
      version: 7.17.3
  interval: 1m0s
```

Configuration files are the same, I'm just changing the metadata's name and the chart itself, but it only seems to work with APM Server and Logstash... What am I doing wrong?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqq8f.png